# lib directory in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have several groups of .jar file and want to put them in different sub-folders in Grails "lib" folder. It seems everything working very well but when I ran application I got the message that it could not find classes in .jar files. when I mixed all .jar files in "lib" folder everything is working fine. Any clues and suggestions?

Reza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably trying to solve the wrong problem. Are these jars available in Maven repos? If so you're way better off defining them as dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy. The lib directory should only be used for jar files that aren't available in a repo somewhere, e.g. an internal library that is shared between projects. But even then I would configure an Artifactory or Nexus server (both free, both easy to setup) to host those private jars. You can also use that server to host private plugins too.